# Error al cargar fuentes de google

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, google-fonts

Intento importar fuentes desde google fonts, pero al cargar da el siguiete error.

> Refused to apply style from 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/memnYaGs126MiZpBA-UFUKXGUehsKKKTjrPW.ttf' because its MIME type ('font/ttf') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Los imports en question:

```
<link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-U1UpcaXcl0Aw.ttf" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v16/memnYaGs126MiZpBA-UFUKXGUehsKKKTjrPW.ttf" rel="stylesheet">
```

He mirado varias soluciones, pero ninguna me ha funcionado.
He intentado añadiendo despues de importar

```
<base href="/">
```

Y añadiendo sin conseguir nada

```
type="text/css"
```

Answer (score 1):

La pagina de google fonts te da el texto a utilizar para importar y es el siguiente

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```